# C program freezes when run

Tags: c, dev-c++

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int x1, x2, x3, 
        y1, y2, y3, 
        ystr1, ystr2, ystr3,  
        xstr1, xstr2, xstr3, 
        sstr1, sstr2, sstr3;

    printf("Insert.");
    scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
    ystr1 = y2 - y1;
    xstr1 = x2 - x1;
    sstr1 = sqrt(pow(xstr1, 2) + pow(ystr1, 2));
    ystr2 = y3 - y2;
    xstr2 = x3 - x2;
    sstr2 = sqrt(pow(xstr2, 2) + pow(ystr2, 2));
    ystr3 = y3 - y1;
    xstr3 = x3 - x1;
    sstr3 = sqrt(pow(xstr1, 2) + pow(ystr1, 2));
    printf("Print %d, %d, %d", sstr1, sstr2, sstr3);
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason this code freezes every time I enter in a single digit. I really don't know what might be causing this. Is it the too many ints?

Comment: `scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d",x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3);` ==> `if (scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3) != 6) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);`

Comment: How do you know it freezes and isn’t just waiting for more input since you’ve told it you want more? Also the compiler doesn’t freeze in any case if you are able to run the program

Comment: Suggestion: don't use `pow(X, 2)` for integers, prefer `X * X` possibly surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: Never use `scanf` for obtaining interactive input from a user.

Comment: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Comment: @Sami Kuhmonen it is not. after 10 seconds it shows "process exited after 5.x seconds with return value....................

Comment: So it *isn't* freezing?

Answer (score 3):

The `scanf` function expects pointers as arguments so that it can modify the variables you're reading into. Remember that all arguments in C are passed by value. If we want to modify something with a function, we need to pass its address in memory (a pointer).

This is made apparent by the warnings your code generates even without explicit warnings enabled.

```
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:14:13: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
            ~^
test.c:14:15: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 3 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
              ~^
test.c:14:17: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
                ~^
test.c:14:19: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 5 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
                  ~^
test.c:14:21: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 6 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
                    ~^
test.c:14:23: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 7 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
     scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

So instead of:

```
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3);
```

You'd want to write:

```
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3);
```

The `&` operator returns the address of a variable.

It's also important to note that `scanf` returns an `int` value. This value indicates the number of values read. You should probably check that `scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3);` returns `6`.

```
if (scanf("%d%d%d%d%d%d", &x1, &y1, &x2, &y2, &x3, &y3) == 6) {
   ...
}
```

Another thing you may wish to do is set initial values for your variables. If `scanf` fails, you'd still have that initial value.

Comment: I don't think this explains OP's "freezing" issue. However, OP has not provided sufficient information to answer that part of the question, so I am still upvoting the answer.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel the missing `&`  *can* account for freezing or any other misbehaviour. The `scanf()` function might not even `return`, so that's hugely more important than checking how many successful conversions (which requires that it does return).

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes, you are right that the missing `&` invokes undefined behavior, so it can be the cause of anything going wrong. However, I would have expected a "segmentation fault" or "access violation" error message in that case, instead of it simply freezing. Therefore, I strongly suspect that OP is not mentioning important details.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel possibly, but not if there is no OS.

Comment: @WeatherVane, at the OP's level of experience I think we can put that possibility solidly in the "outside chance" category.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel agreed, and I am not of the 'nasal demons' school, with or without a chortling laugh.